# How can we maintain asymptotic normality with slight change?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, convergence, asymptotics

If $(X_n-\mu_n)/\sigma_n\rightarrow_{d} N(0,1)$ (i.e., $X_n$ is $AN(\mu_n,\sigma_n^2)$), I want to show the following two statements:

(1) $X_n$ is $AN(\bar{\mu}_n, \bar{\sigma}_n^2)$ if and only if $\frac{\bar{\sigma}_n}{\sigma_n} \rightarrow 1$ and $\frac{\mu_n - \bar{\mu}_n}{\sigma_n}\rightarrow 0$.

(2) $a_nX_n + b_n$ is $AN(\mu_n,\sigma_n^2)$ if and only if $a_n\rightarrow 1$ and $\frac{\mu_n(a_n-1) + b_n}{\sigma_n} \rightarrow 0$.

Actually, I believe that the "if part" is relatively easy to prove due to the decomposition. However, I have no idea on how to prove the "only if" part.

Comment: If this is an exercise that you were given, please add the self-study tag. https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

I won't solve this for you, but the way I'd go on about it is that (just to use an example) I'd assume $a_n\not\to 1$ (or any other of the required conditions not fulfilled). This means that there is a subsequence $a_m$ so that either $|a_m|\to\infty$ or $a_m\to z$ with $z\neq 1$. This is a consequence of the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Either $a_n$ is bounded, then there is a subsequence in some minimum distance from 1 (as $a_n\not\to 1$), which must converge, or it is unbounded, which means there is a subsequence with $|a_m|\to\infty$.

Looking at such a subsequence only, in the former case $a_mX_m$ will be $AN(z\mu_n,z^2\sigma_n^2)$, and no choice of $b_m$ can repair the variance (it may take a bit of effort to make this precise). You can also show that it can't be repaired for $|a_m|\to\infty$, and similar arguments should rule out any of the other conditions to be violated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not stated clearly. Here is what I understand, but not everybody will necessarily understand the same.

**A.** For result **"1)"**, set $\gamma_n \equiv \bar \mu_n - \mu_n \implies \bar \mu_n = \gamma_n + \mu_n$, and $\bar \sigma_n \equiv \delta_n \sigma_n, \; \delta_n > 0$.

Then, I would understand that the question is whether the stated convergence conditions are equivalent to the statement
$$\frac{X_n -\bar \mu_n }{\bar \sigma_n} \to_d N(0,1) \implies ?? \frac{X_n -\mu_n - \gamma_n }{\delta_n \sigma_n} \to_d N(0,1)$$

$$??\implies  \frac 1 {\delta_n}\frac{X_n -\mu_n}{\sigma_n}  - \frac{\gamma_n }{\delta_n \sigma_n}\to_d N(0,1)$$

**B.** For result **"2)"**, we have
$$Y_n \equiv a_nX_n + b_n \implies E(Y_n) = a_n\mu_n + b_n,\; SD(Y_n) = a_n\sigma_n$$
and we wonder whether the stated convergence conditions are equivalent to the statement
$$\frac{Y_n - \mu_n}{\sigma_n} ??\to_d N(0,1) \implies \frac{Y_n - E(Y_n) +E(Y_n) -\mu_n}{SD(Y_n) [\sigma_n/SD(Y_n)]} ??\to_d N(0,1)$$

$$??\implies a_n\frac{Y_n - E(Y_n)}{SD(Y_n)} + \frac{a_n\mu_n + b_n -\mu_n}{\sigma_n}??\to_d N(0,1)$$